# The value of the firestore field sums

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore file and I want to add the value of the field "quantity" in all files (all together and displayed in label), is there a way to do this?[image]

For example, the value of "quantity" in the first file field is "100", the value of "quantity" in the second file field is "50", and the value of "quantity" in the third file field is "1000"
100+50+1000=
Displayed in label:1150

Here is my current code:

```
func getDatas2(){        
        self.db.collection("Users").document(UID!).collection("AiBuyPost").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error while getting data from server!" )
        }else{
            if snapshot?.isEmpty != true && snapshot != nil {
                self.postArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                for document in snapshot!.documents{                    
                    if let quantity = document.data()["quantity"] as? Int{
                        self.totalVotes += quantity
                        self.new.text = String(self.totalVotes)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you already debug the code you shared? If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: And using tableviewCell will always update the infinite sum...

Comment: At present, it is running normally, and finally solved this problem...Thank you for your teaching!
Then why do I use tableviewCell to refresh infinitely and keep adding up?